# Scrollable Textarea in Bootstrap-4 Modal footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap-4 modal in my Angular-6 project. 
For modal, Modal-Header is of fixed height, Modal-Body is scrollable and Modal-Footer is of variable height but not scrollable.

Below is my basic HTML:

```css
/*for debugging purpose*/
.modal {
  display: block !important;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-color: #e0e0e7;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 55px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.comment-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.textarea {
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.textarea:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: 'Type your comments here';
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="comment-input">
          <div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make my textarea scrollable after insertion of four lines of text. Before the insertion of four lines of text, modal-footer should increase its height as textarea grows. I am trying to do the same by above HTML and CSS but somehow modal-footer is not getting increased by the height of textarea. Every possible solution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the `modal body` you need to set `max-height` along with `overflow-y: scroll` property, so it will scroll when the content is over `max-height`.

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It's opposite for the `modal footer`, you need to remove the `max-height` in the text area and also the `overflow:auto` attribute of `.textarea`

```css
/*for debugging purpose*/

.modal {
  display: block !important;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-color: #e0e0e7;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 55px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.comment-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.textarea:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: 'Type your comments here';
  position: absolute;
}

.modal-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
          nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
          est laborum." Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
          veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam
          est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
          suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="comment-input">
          <div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my entire modal should have max-height of 100vh only and in that space, it should have Modal-header of 75px height, Modal-Body and Modal-Footer should be adjustable with each other. What I mean is as Modal-Footer grows up to 110px of height Modal-body should shrink accordingly. Modal-Body should not be restricted to some max-height value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property, it should be `min-height` instead of `max-height`, please refer the below example!

```css
.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-color: #e0e0e7;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 55px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.comment-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.textarea {
  max-height: 80px !important;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.textarea:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: 'Type your comments here';
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" role="dialog"> <!-- I have removed the modal class so that the modal is visible, please ignore this one change -->
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"></div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="comment-input">
            <div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```